# use code behind to pop aspx confirmation message

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclientclick

I need to return a confirmation message to OnClientClick event. The problem is I have to get the message from stored procedure, and I don't seem to call my function right.

```
 <asp:ImageButton 
OnClientClick="return confirm(<%# GetConfirmExportMessage()%>);"            
OnClick="btnExportRed_Click" 
runat="server" 
ImageUrl="~/Images/excel_red.gif" 
ID="btnExportRed" 
AlternateText="Export all records!"/>
```

My code behind:

```
public string GetConfirmExportMessage()
    {
        string xmlFilterForExport = Parameters.ToString().Split('+')[4].Trim();
        string alertMessage = companiesSearcher.GetAlertMessage(xmlFilterForExport, 1, null, null, IdSegment, 1, Convert.ToInt32(RoDB2004.BLL.clsUsers.UserID));

        return alertMessage;
    }
```

Comment: `confirm` is a javascript function that takes a string as argument(the message to be displayed). A string must be wrapped in `"` or `'` in javascript. Otherwise the js engine assumes that you're trying to call another function or variable with that name. Hence this don't work: `confirm(my name is anna)` and this works: `confirm('my name is anna')`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using equal sign instead of pound (and don't forget your single quotes).

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('<%= GetConfirmExportMessage()%>');"
```

However, if you're ImageButton is located inside a DataGrid or GridView, the server-side code will not be evaluated and will yeield an alert saying <%= GetConfirmExportMessage()%> instead of the real message.

To get around this problem (and to increase performance, throughput, etc.), output your message once to a variable, then alert the contents of the variable.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var myMessage = '<%= GetConfirmExportMessage()%>';
</script>
```

Later, in the GridView...

```
OnClientClick="return confirm(myMessage);"
```

You save throughput by repeating a small variable name like "myMessage" and avoid repeating some big message.  Also note, that the method `GetConfirmExportMessage` isn't called dozens of times increasing performance.

If your message is specific to data within a current row and not static like "Are you sure?", then I suggest you perform this operation inside the GridView's `RowDataBound` event.  You'll have full access to the `ImageButton` and to the data the current row is binding to, which makes it very easy to setup server-side.  Check out the `FindControl()` method, or if you know the exact location, just reference it and unbox the object.

```
protected void gvMyGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton ibtn = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnExportRed");
        if(ibtn != null)
        {
            ibtn.ClientClick = "return confirm('" + GetConfirmExportMessage() + "');";
        }
    }
}
```

As an alternative solution, maybe you should look into WebMethods, AJAX and jQuery.  This solution is probably the better one because the data is not sent to the client and only retrieved when necessary.

Comment: I've tried both  OnClientClick="return confirm('<%# GetConfirmExportMessage()%>');" and  OnClientClick="return confirm('<%= GetConfirmExportMessage()%>');", but I only get <%# GetConfirmExportMessage()%> or <%# GetConfirmExportMessage()%> in the alert message. When using just OnClientClick="return confirm(<%= GetConfirmExportMessage()%>);", I get a script error.

Comment: Is the ImageButton inside another control's template like a datagrid?

Comment: Error Message: Syntax error  the client side code works fine. Yes, the ImageButton is inside a GridView.

Comment: @Anna - I've updated my answer to include some alternatives for a GridView. And do read up on WebMethods and jQuery, it's actually pretty easy to implement.

Comment: thank you for all your help. I have read about WebMethods, Ajax and JQuery, but I wasn't able to implement any of that, as I have to call a non static method in order to get my message. I ended up implementing a MessageBox alert on the btnExportRed_Click.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('<%= GetConfirmExportMessage()%>');"
```

Note that this will be populated when the page is rendered, not when the button is clicked, so you may as well use

```
btnExportRed.OnClientClick = "javascript:return confirm('" + GetConfirmExportMessage() + "');"
```

in your code behind.

Answer (score 1):

you need to wrap your confirm in `'`

```
<asp:ImageButton 
    OnClientClick="return confirm('<%# GetConfirmExportMessage()%>');"            
    OnClick="btnExportRed_Click" 
    runat="server" 
    ImageUrl="~/Images/excel_red.gif" 
    ID="btnExportRed" 
    AlternateText="Export all records!"/>
```